# How to get the input range and cell link of an excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am new to VBA programming so please don't be offended with this non-technical question.

I have an excel workbook with macros which was passworded. I was able to break the password using [this tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlhK5.png)

I edited the file to suit my purpose but I wasn't able to change the values to the drop down list. How can I get the input range and the cell link of the excel sheet in the picture below?

[image]

What does that line in the Input range and cell link mean and how can I get to update the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop down list is getting its values from the Input Range.  So in a worksheet called Data References (it may be hidden, it may not), in cells U10 to U14, there are some values which are what appear in the drop down list.

When you select an item in the drop down list, it places the number of the item you selected in the Cell link (cell U17).  So if you pick the first item in the list, the value 1 will be placed into the cell U17 in the Data References worksheet.   This numeric value allows you index into the cells (using a formula or code), to work out the value which was selected (for example using an OFFSET formula, you can work out from the Cell link value, what value in the list in the range U10 to U14 is actually selected).

If you want to expand, adjust the list - simply add a list of items into some cells somewhere, and add the cell reference in the Input Range section.  The drop down will pick up the values from these cells.

Comment: Hi @Smackenzie, That I know already. But the challenge is the worksheet may be hidden. I can't see any sheet called datareference in the workbook. If the sheet is hidden, how can I unhide it?

Comment: Hi @Smackenzie , You response guided me in the right direction. I had to enable the Data Reference sheet in the vba code to make it visible.

Comment: Hi.  Glad you fixed it.  If your question had mentioned you couldn't see the sheet - I would have given a different answer ;)